# Sonar use computeIfAbsent

Tags: java, dictionary, sonarqube

I have this method:

```
private static void method(Integer key, final Map<Integer, Integer> aMap) {
  var value = aMap.get(key);
  if(value == null) {
    value = 0;
  }
  aMap.put(key, value + 1);
}
```

and Sonar analysis is telling me I should use `Map#computIfAbsent`, but I don't really know how to ensure the same result, since computeIfAbsent will update the map with 0, something which is not done as it is right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to want to put `1` in the map if no value exists, otherwise add `1` to the current value. I agree that using `computeIfAbsent` is not the best substitute for your current code. However, your use-case sounds like it would be perfectly solved by [`Map#merge(K,V,BiFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)):

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value or is associated with null, associates it with the given non-null value. Otherwise, replaces the associated value with the results of the given remapping function, or removes if the result is null.

For example:

```java
static void method(Integer key, Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
    map.merge(key, 1, Math::addExact);
}
```

I used `Math::addExact` to prevent silent overflows. Whether you decide to keep that or use something like `Integer::sum` is up to you.

---

Also, a benefit of `merge` is that it's thread-safe for `ConcurrentMap` implementations, if that matters here.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with [putIfAbsent()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) -- passed Sonar here :)

```java
private static void method(Integer key, final Map<Integer, Integer> aMap) {
    aMap.putIfAbsent(key, 0);  
    var value = aMap.get(key);
    aMap.put(key, value + 1);
}
```

Two simple JUnit test cases:

```java
@Test
void testWithAbsentKey() {
    final var map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    method(1, map);

    assertEquals(1, map.get(1));
}

@Test
void testWithKeyPresent() {
    final var map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    map.put(1, 1);
    method(1, map);

    assertEquals(2, map.get(1));
}
```

Please bear in mind - just like the original code provided by OP - this solution is not thread-safe!

Comment: This is better than the OP's code, but, just like the OP's code, it suffers from not being thread-safe. If method is called twice from different threads at the same time, the map entry may be increased by 1 instead of 2.

Comment: @k314159 Since OP's code isn't thread safe, I'd assume that's not a requirement.

Comment: Dear @k314159 you're absolutely right, I will edit my answer to reflect that. Despite it's a static method I forgot to consider thread-safety. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using computeIfAbsent would be easier if you could change the map value to `AtomicInteger` so you'd change to `aMap.computeIfAbsent(key, AtomicInteger::new).incrementAndGet()`:

```
private static void method(Integer key, final Map<Integer, AtomicInteger> aMap) {
    aMap.computeIfAbsent(key, AtomicInteger::new).incrementAndGet();
  }
```

The above has benefit of thread-safe counter updates when used with `ConcurrentHashMap`, as there is no risk of two threads using get-put inconsistently.

Comment: two consecutive thread-safe calls are not automatically thread safe

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel What circumstances makes `map.computeIfAbsent(key, AtomicInteger::new).incrementAndGet()` not thread-safe, when the map is `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Comment: you could get your thread swapped out between those two calls

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel Thread scheduling would not change the outcome. Just see docs for [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) and [incrementAndGet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet())

Comment: @PerdiEstaquel while your comment is true in general, I agree with DuncG that in this case it's thread safe. That's because, between the calls to the two methods, the two threads are guaranteed to be working on the same instance of AtomicInteger.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to implement it that sonar will like, using `getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue)` :

```java
private static void method(Integer key, final Map<Integer, Integer> aMap) {
    aMap.put(key, aMap.getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1);
}
```